# Are parsers generated by FSYacc thread safe?

Tags: f#, fsyacc

If I generate a parser using FSYacc will it be thread safe?

The only reason I ask is because the functions

`Parsing.rhs_start_pos` and `Parsing.symbol_end_pos`

don't *appear* to have any state passed into them, which would lead me to assume that they are getting the current NonTerminal/Symbols from a shared location, is this correct?

After reflecting the code I see that they are getting the postion from a static property

```
internal static IParseState parse_information
{
    get
    {
        return parse_information;
    }
    set
    {
        parse_information = value;
    }
}
```

Is this correct? If so what can I do about it?

Edit: I also see a static method called `set_parse_state`

```
public static void set_parse_state(IParseState x)
{
    parse_information = x;
}
```

But that still wont solve my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't like to answer my own question, however since this could save someone else a world of grief someday I will.

It turns out that the functions provided in the parsing module are NOT thread safe.
What you can do however is access the `parseState` "variable", which is of type `IParseState`, in your nonterminal action.

For example (rough but work with me):
If you have a NonTerminal like

```
%token<string> NAME
%%
Person:
       NAME NAME { $1 (* action *) }
```

The code that gets generated is:

```
(fun (parseState : Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Parsing.IParseState) ->
      let _1 = (let data = parseState.GetInput(1) in 
                           (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.unbox data : string)
                ) in
      Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.box((_1) : 'Person)
);
```

So you can interact with that parseState object in the same fashion.

```
%token<string> NAME
%%
Person:
       NAME NAME { parseState.DoStuff(); }
```

The `rhs_start_pos` method basically does this:

```
let startPos,endPos = parseState.InputRange(n)
```

and the `symbol_end_pos` does this:

```
let startSymb,endSymb = parseState.ResultRange
```

I hope this helps